# Add number to the dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe pandas that looks something like this:

```
     col1    col2  col3  col4 
0  name.jpg     1     0     1  
1  name2.jpg    0     0     1  
2  name3.jpg    1     0     0  
3  name4.jpg    0     1     0  
4  name5.jpg    0     0     1
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
     col1        col2  col3  col4 
0  1.name.jpg     1     0     1  
1  2.name2.jpg    0     0     1  
2  3.name3.jpg    1     0     0  
3  4.name4.jpg    0     1     0  
4  5.name5.jpg    0     0     1
```

Comment: df.index.to_series().add(1).astype(str)+'.'+df['col1']

Comment: this works fine, but in this way I lose the column name I need. When I did it my way was the same

Comment: df['col1'] = df.index.to_series().add(1).astype(str)+'.'+df['col1']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['col1']=(df.index+1).astype(str)+'.'+df['col1']
print(df)
```

---

```
          col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.name.jpg     1     0     1
1  2.name2.jpg     0     0     1
2  3.name3.jpg     1     0     0
3  4.name4.jpg     0     1     0
4  5.name5.jpg     0     0     1
```

Comment: plus1 like white flag ;)